# Match values from one object to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, key-value

I have two arrays of objects:

```js
[ 
  0: {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3},
  1: {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3} 
]

[  
  0: {stop_id: 173, file_id: "1", key_type: null, key_value: "0020", seg_beg: 32},
  1: {stop_id: 176, file_id: "1", key_type: null, key_value: "0201", seg_beg: 10},
  2: {stop_id: 176, file_id: "1", key_type: null, key_value: "0201", seg_beg: 10}
]
```

I need to check to see if the values of any of the keys in the first object, match any of the values of the **key_value**...keys, in the second object, and then set a variable further up to the stop_id value in the matched record. Like this:

```js
if(object1.value === object2.key_value){
    match = object2[iterator].stop_id;
}
```

To simplify this, I have attempted to just grab the values of the first object:

```js
//pd.segs is object 1
let pdSegValues = [];

for(let i=0;i<pd.segs.length;i++){
  pdSegValues.push(Object.values(pd.segs[i]));
}
```

But that gets me an array of arrays again, and basically puts me back in the same situation. I'm suffering from a fried brain, and admittedly have a weakness for loops. Can anyone show me a decent way to accomplish what I need here?

Comment: `and then do something` This may be important - do you need to do something *with the matched objects*, or do you just need to know whether a match exists? The first results in easy code, the second results in very slightly more complicated code

Comment: I need to set a variable further up eqaul to the stop_id value of the matched record

Comment: Edited question accordingly :)

Comment: Do you just want a yes/no boolean for whether or not a match exists?

Comment: @mark meyer, no I need to set a variable higher up to the stop_id value of the matched record. See the edited question above

Comment: @Jensen010 can you include example input with expected output? I'm having trouble understanding what you're looking for.

Comment: Can't do this tonight but I will put together a plunger or something  tomorrow morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by collecting the values you want to test and then using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
let arr1 = [
    {"a1": "value1", "b1": "value2"},
    {"a2": "0020", "b2": "value22"},
    {"a3": "value111", "b3": "0201"}
];

let arr2 = [  
    {stop_id: 173, file_id: "1", key_type: null, key_value: "0020", seg_beg: 32},
    {stop_id: 176, file_id: "1", key_type: null, key_value: "0201", seg_beg: 10},
    {stop_id: 176, file_id: "1", key_type: null, key_value: "0201", seg_beg: 10}
];

// accumulate unique arr1 values to an array
let arr1Values = Array.from(arr1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    Object.values(curr).forEach(v => acc.add(v));
    return acc;
}, new Set()));

// accumulate all unique arr2 "key_value"
let arr2KeyValues = arr2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc.add(curr.key_value);
    return acc;
}, new Set());

console.log(arr1Values);
console.log(Array.from(arr2KeyValues));

// Test if any of the values in objects in the first array are 
// equal to any of the key_values in the second array
console.log(arr1Values.some(k => arr2KeyValues.has(k)));
```

Comment: This is interesting, I'll test it out and get back

Comment: This is a really good solution, and much more concise than anything I had attempted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're going to have to compare every object in one array to every object's keys in another array. An initial brute force approach has 3 nested for loops:

```
// Loop through the objects in the first array
for (const objectA of arrayA) {

  // Loop through that object's keys
  for (const key in objectA) {

    // Loop through the objects in the second array
    for (const objectB of arrayB) {

      if (objectA[key] === objectB.key_value) {
        // do all the stuff
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That was what I feared, although there are a few things in your answer I didn't think of. I'll give them a shot

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing, just to leave a record :)

```
let stopRules = pd.stopRules;
let pdSegs = pd.segs;
let routeStopsTest = [];

//Returns a flat array of all unique values in first object
//Thanks @slider!
let pdSegValues = Array.from(pdSegs.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  Object.values(curr).forEach(v => acc.add(v));
  return acc;
}, new Set()));

//Pushes all objects from stopRules array to a holding array
//When they match individual segments in the pdSegs array
pdSegValues.forEach( seg => {
  let nullTest = stopRules.filter(o => o.key_value === seg);
  if(nullTest.length !== 0){
    routeStopsTest.push(nullTest);
  }else{}
});
```

Then all I have to do is flatten the resulting array of objects, and I have the results I need, which I can then loop through for the original purpose.

Thank you, everyone, for the insightful input. I've learned a fair bit here :)